# Layout problems (backgrounds and blocks region)

Tags: blocks, media, theming

I'm a non professionist dealing with drupal for the first time and it's killing me. I'm trying to create a page without having to code but it seems impossible! I need to adjust the position of the main menu (**how can I move the writings to the center?**), then I need to put a **background**, and basically I need very simple assistance to create this web site for an exam, please help me :'(
(yes, i tried to read the guide on drupal.com but it's too difficult for a non-expert

Answer (score 0):

You would have to [learn CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) and [how to work with themes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming) to do this yourself.

An alternative option, for no code solution, you could use [Glazed Builder](https://demo.sooperthemes.com/glazed-main/). However, it's not free, but might be worth the price of admission if you no time to learn how to code.

**Important:** There is Glazed builder for Drupal 7 & Drupal 8, remember to get the version of the Drupal version that you are using, as the 7 version will not work for Drupal 8 and vice versa.

Comment: The problem is that it should be an exam without coding and without having to buy anything. I actually know some css, but i have no idea of how to edit the theme..however, thanks a lot.

Comment: @LauraMancini all you have to do is add the CSS to your theme's .css file, usually named style.css. If it's Drupal 7 should be in `/sites/all/themes/[your_theme]/css` folder. If its Drupal 8 `/themes/[your_theme]/css` folder. I am assuming you're not using the Drupal default theme called "Bartik".

Comment: @LauraMancini After modifying your theme's .css file, remember to clear/flush the cache in order to see the changes.

Comment: no i'm not using bartik, and I'm using drupal 7